# Showing the User photo profile From Facebook with bad quality

Tags: android, facebook, picasso

I'm getting the user photo profile from Facebook and using the Picasso library to show the image rounded, the problem is the image is showing with a bad quality, I can't see well the image. But in other apps for example Tinder, etc the same photo is showing very well.

This is my code:

```
CircleTransformation transformation;

Picasso.with(this)
        .load(urlImage)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
        .resize(50, 50)
        .centerCrop()
        .transform(transformation)
        .into(ivPhoto);


public class CircleTransformation implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) { source.recycle();  }

        Bitmap.Config config = source.getConfig() != null ? source.getConfig() : Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, config);
        //Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size/2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() { return "circle"; }
}
```

How can I show correctly the user photo profile from Facebook?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are resizing an image to 50x50 before doing a crop to the aspect ratio? it means centercrop is either unneccessary or should be done before the resizing. Furthermore 50x50 is really small.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I can put 200x200. I got the same result. From Facebook I'm getting this Url: "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/ **p50x50** \/1965046_10152607544607226_1837802686760326562_n.jpg?oh=cb45ff92019d3ea8785b37552ce029a03&oe=584E0ED3". It seems the image is always 50x50. I don't know why in other apps is showing well the same image that I got from Facebook.